# Animation always firing because state always changes on scroll in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, state, pose

So I'm using React/[Pose](https://popmotion.io/pose) to animate a `Showcase` component like the [Postmates fleet website](https://fleet.postmates.com/fleet-app/) seen here:

[image: Here's an example of it]

I'm **almost** there but I can't figure out the last bit. Basically, I have an array of items:

```
const chapters = [
  {
    content: "1",
    title: "Create your profile"
  },
  {
    content: "2",
    title: "See their rating"
  },
  {
    content: "3",
    title: "Forgot annoying requests"
  },
  {
    content: "4",
    title: "Block them"
  },
  {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
    content: "5",
    title: "Make your decision"
  },
  {
    content: "6",
    title: "Time elapses"
  },
  {
    content: "7",
    title: "Complete"
  }
];
```

And a `handleScroll(e)` method which does a few things:

1. Detects when scrolling through the component
2. When scrolling through a chapter, it updates `this.state.content` and `this.state.title` with the correct chapter content from `chapters`:

--

```
// loop through the chapters
for (let index = 0; index < chapters.length; index++) {
  const chapterHeight = componentHeight;
  topOfChapter.push(componentTopY + chapterHeight * index);
  bottomOfChapter.push(componentTopY * 2 + chapterHeight * index);

  // when scrolling through the component
  if (
    scrollY >= component.offsetTop &&
    scrollY <= component.offsetHeight + window.innerHeight
  ) {
    // when scrolling through a chapter
    if (
      scrollY >= topOfChapter[index] &&
      scrollY <= bottomOfChapter[index]
    ) {
      // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
      console.log(`Scrolling through chapter ${index + 1}`);
      this.setState({
        animate: !this.state.animate,
        content: chapters[index].content,
        title: chapters[index].title
      });
      // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
      console.log(topOfChapter[index], "topOfChapter[index]");
      // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
      console.log(bottomOfChapter[index], "bottomOfChapter[index]");
    }
  } else {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
    console.log("exited the component");
  }
}
```

The problem is that my animation is always firing because `this.state.animate` is always changing on scroll.

I need to fire the animation only when the chapter changes, not all the time that is scrolling, but I cannot figure out how.

I asked a question a few hours ago, which did not have the animations, but I think the question only really makes sense in the context of animating.

Any help is really appreciated!

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-hamilton-696hh)

Comment: Could you share the whole component?

Comment: Hey @Alvaro the whole component is linked in the sandbox. Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: I see it, didnt notice the sandbox. Thanks.

Comment: No worries, thank you for taking a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-leftpad-33j4y should be the effect you are looking for.

There are number of things I changed to get this into a usable state and assumptions I had to make.

---

Once the exit animation is finished, you want to start the `enter` animation of the next chapter.  The problem you had was, you already lost track of the previous chapter, as you had already updated the `state` to the next chapter, whilst also triggering the animation repeatedly.

I've resolved this by now tracking, the currentChapter (the chapter which is currently visible) and the nextChapter (the chapter you wish to transition into).

---

```
    <Text
        pose={animate ? "enter" : "exit"}
        onPoseComplete={this.onPoseComplete}
    >
```

https://popmotion.io/pose/api/posed/#posed-props-onposecomplete

When an animation is finished, `pose` will callback on `onPoseComplete`. If the animation was false, set the currentChapter to be the nextChapter e.g.

When we exit Chapter 0, going into 1:

```
{
   animate: false,
   currentChapter: 0,
   nextChapter: 1,
}
```

This starts the Exit animation on the currentChapter. When the animation finishes, `onPoseComplete` is called and, if the animate was false i.e. exit animation is now finished, update the state to:

```
{
   animate: true,
   currentChapter: 1,
   nextChapter: 1,
}
```

Which will now starts the `enter` animation on currentChapter, which was now changed to 1.

---

Now that we are tracking the chapter index, we don't need the `title`, `content` state which I've removed.

I've simplified the handleScroll logic to what I think is equivalent.  By dividing the scrollY with the `window.innerHeight`, we can get the index of the chapter you want visible.

---

```
  style={{ height: `${100 * chapters.length}vh` }}
```

We know how many chapters there are, so simply multiplied the number of chapters with 100vh

```
onPoseComplete = () => {
```

As you are using `create-react-app`, you have `transform-class-properties` which allows you to create an arrow function rather than `.bind`.

Answer (score 0):

you should cache the positions of the chapters by saving it as an array to the component's state only when the page loads with the chapters data from your db and whenever a user resizes the screen (because the heights of the components changes when this happens)

then on scroll compare scrollY against that array of chapter positions to identify where you are at:

```js
this.state.chapters.forEach( (chapter, index) => {
  if ( scrollY >= chapter.top && scrollY <= chapter.bottom && currentScrolledChapter !== chapter ) {
    currentScrolledChapter = chapter;
  }
});
```

and depending on where it is do the following check:

```js
if ( currentScrolledChapter.title !== this.state.title ) {
  this.setState( {
    animate: !this.state.animate,
    content: chapters[index].content,
    title: chapters[index].title
  } );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use this one https://www.react-reveal.com/examples/common/Fade

so you will not need your custom implementation?

Comment: I need to use Pose unfortunately

Comment: maybe you can check title, so if title in state is not the same as on chapters[index]
only then update state
`
this.setState((prevState) => {
            if (prevState.title !== chapters[index].title) {
              return {
                animate: !this.state.animate,
                content: chapters[index].content,
                title: chapters[index].title
              }
            }
          });
`

Comment: or  if (
          scrollY >= topOfChapter[index] &&
          scrollY <= bottomOfChapter[index] &&
 this.state.title !== chapters[index].title
        ) {

Comment: Thanks @Oleksandr I'm out at the moment I'm going to try what you said when I get home in an hour. I appreciate it!

Comment: I've done a Codesandbox with your suggestion, but it's buggy. :( I'm too tired to investigate further now, so I'll check tomorrow. Thanks anyway, and here's the Codesandbox if you were interested: https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-sea-ptg9u